# Charset on Psliwa PHPPdf Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, pdf, encoding, fonts

Concerning the PdfBundle on Symfony2 proposed by Psliwa,
When I try to add my custom font I have this error :

> Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from 'MacRoman' to 'UTF-16BE' is not allowed in .../vendor/zendframework/zendpdf/library/ZendPdf/BinaryParser/AbstractBinaryParser.php line 431

In my config.yml I have :

```
fonts_file: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Travel/PdfBundle/Resources/config/fonts.xml"
```

In my template I have :

```
<dynamic-page encoding="UTF-8" font-type="FFInfoFonts">
```

In my Controller:

```
public function pdfAction(Request $request, $ce, $year) {
    $format = $this->get('request')->get('_format');
    return $this->render(sprintf('TravelPdfBundle:PointsCard:pdf.%s.twig', $format));
}
```

And in my fonts.xml I have :

```
<font name="FFInfoFonts">
    <normal src="font/FF Info fonts/police Web/InfoDisplayComp.ttf" />
</font>
```

Anyone has an idea on how to force the charset?

Comment: i haven't used this bundle but i had a pretty good experience with [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle) for PDF creation. might be helpful ... :)

Comment: Hello, tanks for your help. I know KnpSnappyBundle but I want change method for html->pdf to xml->pdf